# User:admin credentials on Ambari UI are not in sync with Ranger

Tags: ambari, hdp, apache-ranger

Ambari shows me an alert message:

"Ranger Admin password check
User:admin credentials on Ambari UI are not in sync with Ranger"

How I can resolve this ? What should I need to do.

I have tried to set the same password for (amb_ranger_admin, admin, etc) but it didn't help.

My version of Ambari is 2.7.1
HDP 3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

This topic seems to have been discussed here: https://community.hortonworks.com/answers/221995/view.html

To summarize, the key steps are:

1. Set the password first in ranger and then in ambari
2. Check if the passwords are the same
3. If they are not the same? : Analyze which one (likely Ambari) is not updating the config
4. If they are the same? : Analyze why you still get the warning